# Cannot Access Disposed Object - Xamarin.Forms / FirebaseFirestore, is it bug or my fault?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.android

Hi i am facing issue using Xamarin.Forms with FirebaseFirestore
The code is sometimes throwing "Cannot Access Disposed object" (particularly when it is called second time)
The code is used inside Android Project.

If anyone has experienced this i would like any kind of advices you got.
thanks in advance.

```
 public async Task<ObservableCollection<PortfolioDetails>> GetPortfoliosAsync()
       {

           ObservableCollection<PortfolioDetails> PortfolioList = new ObservableCollection<PortfolioDetails>();

           object _result = await FirebaseFirestore.Instance
               .Collection(Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Uid)
               .Get();

           if (_result is QuerySnapshot docs)
           {

               foreach (DocumentSnapshot y in docs.Documents)
               {

                   var _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<PortfolioDetails>();


                   var secondResult = await FirebaseFirestore.Instance
                     .Collection(Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Uid)
                     .Document(y.Id)
                     .Collection("Transactions")
                     .Get();
                   var result = new PortfolioDetails();

                   if (secondResult is QuerySnapshot _docs)
                   {
                       CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
                       decimal portfolioValue = 0;
                       decimal portfolioBuyPrice = 0;
                       foreach (var i in _docs.Documents)
                       {
                           portfolioBuyPrice += decimal.Parse(i.GetString("qty")) * decimal.Parse(i.GetString("buyprice"));

                           switch (i.GetString("type"))
                           {
                               case "stock":
                                   var securities = await Yahoo.Symbols(i.Id).Fields(Field.RegularMarketPrice).QueryAsync();
                                   var symbol = securities[i.Id];
                                   portfolioValue += decimal.Parse(symbol[Field.RegularMarketPrice].ToString()) * decimal.Parse(i.GetString("qty"));
                                   break;

                               case "crypto":
                                   var price = AllClass.Data.Find(x => x.id.Contains(i.Id));
                                   portfolioValue += decimal.Parse(price.current_price) * decimal.Parse(i.GetString("qty"));
                                   break;
                           }
                       }


                       result.Price = "$" + portfolioValue;

                       if (portfolioValue > 10000 || portfolioValue < -10000)
                       {
                           result.Price = "$" + Math.Round(portfolioValue / 1000M, 2) + "K";
                       }
                       if (portfolioValue > 1000000 || portfolioValue < -1000000)
                       {
                           result.Price = "$" + Math.Round(portfolioValue / 1000000M, 2) + "M";
                       }

                       var valueDifference = portfolioValue - portfolioBuyPrice;
                       var tempValueDifference = valueDifference.ToString();

                       string valueDifferenceString;
                       if (valueDifference > 0)
                       {
                           result.BuyPrice_Color = "#4bb543";
                           if (valueDifference > 10000)
                           {
                               tempValueDifference = Math.Round(valueDifference / 1000M, 2) + "K";
                           }
                           if (portfolioValue > 1000000)
                           {
                               tempValueDifference = Math.Round(valueDifference / 1000000M, 2) + "M";
                           }
                           valueDifferenceString = "+$" + tempValueDifference;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           result.BuyPrice_Color = "#ff0033";
                           if (valueDifference < -10000)
                           {
                               tempValueDifference = Math.Round(valueDifference / 1000M, 2) + "K";
                           }
                           if (valueDifference < -1000000)
                           {
                               tempValueDifference = Math.Round(valueDifference / 1000000M, 2) + "M";
                           }
                           valueDifferenceString = "-$" + tempValueDifference.Replace("-", "");
                       }

                       var percentageDifference = Math.Round((portfolioValue - portfolioBuyPrice) / (portfolioBuyPrice / 100), 2);
                       string percentageDifferenceString;
                       if (percentageDifference > 0)
                       {
                           percentageDifferenceString = "(+" + percentageDifference + "%)";
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           percentageDifferenceString = "(" + percentageDifference + "%)";
                       }
                       result.BuyPrice = valueDifferenceString + " " + percentageDifferenceString;
                   }
                       PortfolioDetails PortfolioObj = result;
                   PortfolioObj.PortfolioName = y.Id;
                   PortfolioList.Add(PortfolioObj);
               }
           }
               return PortfolioList;
       }
```

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: which line of code throws the error? Set breakpoint on first line, and step through code. OR Add some Debug.Writeline lines, with different strings, to see the progress. Especially at beginning and end of method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Instance of the Firebase has sometimes triggered the GC, so before the new instance i handled all my data to C# types, this way, the Java GC wont touch that data.

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? If not, you should mention it in the comments and not as an answer. If yes, accept it.